# How do i catch exceptions from container managed transaction commit?

Tags: java, exception, transactions, ejb, container-managed

I have a `@Stateless` EJB with a `@WebService` interface, using container managed transactions, meaning transactions are  automatically committed by the container after a method has been called if it doesn't throw a system exception.

If i try to `EntityManager.persist(...)` two objects with the same value for a column with a unique constraint on it, the container will throw a `PersistenceException` to the client on commit outside my code. **How do i catch this exception so i can rethrow my own application exception?**

Do i have to commit the transaction manually in my methods to catch exceptions on commit? (And is `EntityManager.flush()` the correct way to do that?) If so, what's the point of having container managed transactions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is unfortunately not possible to catch exceptions from container-managed transaction failure.  As you stated, your best option is to use bean-managed transactions.  Alternatively, you could wrap your EM EJB with a proxy bean that implements the same interface.  Container-managed transactions are appropriate when your code does not need to respond to specific commit failures.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I solved it by doing `EntityManager.flush()` in an `@AroundInvoke` interceptor.

Comment: That might work sometimes, but be careful with isolation levels.  Unless you serialize everything, it's still possible to get failures when the tx commits.